# Why cronned job is not able to open X display connection

Tags: opengl, cron, lwjgl, x11

I have a java app rendering some sprites using LWJGL and OpenGL. It works fine until I move it to remote virtual machine with no phisical graphic card, Mesa 3d with related stuff is used to emulate it there. When I connect via ssh and start job manually it works fine. But being cronned it throws exception

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Pbuffer.createPbuffer(Pbuffer.java:234) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Pbuffer.<init>(Pbuffer.java:219) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Pbuffer.<init>(Pbuffer.java:190) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not open X display connection
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:141) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not open X display connection
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.openDisplay(Native Method) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.incDisplay(LinuxDisplay.java:306) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.internAtom(LinuxDisplay.java:616) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:721) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Obviously something is wrong with X11.

Comment: Because cron jobs have minimal environment. You need at least `DISPLAY` to be set up. See http://serverfault.com/questions/591877/why-cron-job-is-not-able-to-open-x-display-connection

Comment: Thanks dude, but you give me a link to my own post on serverfault

Comment: Funny, that post of yours has a perfectly good answer. Should not have been closed though.

Comment: I'll update the answer there so no more need to keep a clone here.